# What are "Drone Privacy Stakeholders"?

Tags: aviation, drones

I just read [this article](http://www.jdsupra.com/legalnews/first-meeting-of-drone-privacy-39243/) because I am interested in the Wild West that is Drone regulation.

At several points in that article, the term **privacy** is used (privacy *regulations*, privacy *stakeholders*, and so on), but without any concrete specifics, such as:

> The NTIA ... said that the [their] underlying goal is to help stakeholders prepare a set of guidelines for drone use, but not impose the guidelines on drone users.

This is so utterly vague! Privacy can mean a lot of things, such as:

- The collection of, storage and access to flight and other recorded data during drone operation; or
- Regulations/policies surrounding where drones can fly (over private property airspace or not); or
- A drone/drone operator's right to reveal information about themselves mid-flight (for instance, can the FAA or an air traffic controller interrogate drones for identification, metadata, etc.)?

So I ask, from a regulatory/legal perspective, what does the phrase **privacy stakeholder** mean, and how might it apply to this article, and more generally, to the drone industry?

Comment: Who says "privacy stakeholder" is being used as a technical legal term?